# CG to GLSL: f3texRECT equivalent?

Tags: opengl, glsl, cg

I'm trying to convert a CG program to a GLSL program.

What I've done so far seems correct, but the GLSL shader outputs an incorrect output. The *incorrect* behavior is defined by a set of test images.

The only dark point on which I'm investigating is the function `f3texRECT`, which I've translated in `texture`. However, I cannot find any documentation about `f3texRECT`.

Can somebody put some light about?

Comment: This is an XY problem. Why don't you show us the Cg source, the GLSL equivalent, explain what it should produce and what the GLSL is actually producing. Then we can tell you where the problem is.

Comment: I would like to do so, but the IP is protected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

f3texRECT() looks like it would map to [texture()](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/texture.xml) with a sampler2DRect instead of a sampler2D -- meaning the texture coordinates are unnormalized ([0..textureSize-1] instead of [0..1]). The "f3" prefix means the result is a three-channel color. Older versions of GLSL had a textureRect() function for this purpose, but it's been deprecated.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed my problem must be elsewhere. Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

`f3texRECT(..args..)` is exactly equivalent to `texRECT(..args..).xyz` in Cg -- it exists as a holdover from the older HSL which didn't have fully general swizzles.

In GLSL the equivalent function is `texture`, so you should be to use `texture(..arg..).xyz` there too, though the args might be slightly different.

The main confusion translating texture calls from Cg to GLSL is dealing with shadow textures -- shadow texture lookups in Cg use normal samplers but the `tex` call has an extra component in the coordinate.  GLSL has distinct shadow sampler types instead.  So when translating Cg to GLSL you need to figure out which textures are 'normal' textures and which are 'shadow' textures, based on how they are used.  In the rare case that you have a single texture used for both normal and shadow lookups, you need to split it into two samplers for GLSL.